# Avoid database ip, user and pass in jenkinsfile using docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile using scripted sintax, in last step (deploy) i just execute a "docker run" (i will migrate to ansible in future).

My docker image need to point a database through a environment variable, so i'm using this:

```
 docker run -d --env DATABASE_EASYREC_HOST="somehost.com.br" \
 --env DATABASE_EASYREC_PORT="5432" \
 --env DATABASE_EASYREC_NAME="easyrec_stage" \
 --env DATABASE_EASYREC_USER="postgres" \
 --env DATABASE_EASYREC_PASS="Ronaldo1986" \
  -p 8080:8080 --rm --name easyrecadm-stage namespace/myimage:prod
```

As you can see i'm using **somehost.com.br** to locate my database, but i don't guess is a good practice set IP, Port, User and Pass direct in Jenkinsfile because if in future the database change to another machine i need to change my Jenkinsfile. So, i think in some solutions:

1. Use a environment variable from operation system in jenkinsfile, so where jenkins is running this variable should be created.
2. Create a step in Jenkinsfile to ask the port, host , user and pass for database
3. Don't change anything because is a good practice pointing to a database in Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a managed file (1), the custom file provider plugin (2) and the pipeline utility steps plugin (3)

With a managed file as database.json, with id 'database'

```
{"DATABASE_EASYREC_HOST": "somehost.com.br"}
```

This code will read the appropriate custom config:

```
def DB_HOST
configFileProvider(
    [configFile(fileId: 'database', targetLocation: 'database.json')]) {
    def db = readJSON file: 'database.json'
    DB_HOST = db.DATABASE_EASYREC_HOST ?: 'default_value'
}
sh 'docker ...'
```

(1) https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin#ConfigFileProviderPlugin-FileTypes
(2) https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin#ConfigFileProviderPlugin-UsingtheconfigurationfilesinJenkinsPipelines
(3) https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace

An bit deeper use case is described at https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/jenkins-shared-pipeline-libraries-custom-runtime-delgado-garrido/

Comment: So, Should I create a file for each environment ? i.e: database-stage.json, database-qa.json, database-dev.json

Comment: Thats one option. Another one would be creating a single database.json, with the expected keys for the different environments (or switching to a third party solution as ansible, to handle environments and secrets )